# How can I use the credentials from Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute/DevOps Plugin in Jenkins to build a custom OCI image using a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-plugins, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

The credentials should be able to be used as a variable.

```
stage('Create-oci-instance') {
                    withCredentials([OracleCloudInfrastructure('credential-id')]) {
                        sh '''
                        sed -i -e "s#USER_OCID#$#$USER_ID" oci-credentials.hcl
                        sed -i -e "s#TENANCY_OCID#$TENANT_ID#"oci-credentials.hcl
                        sed -i -e "s#FINGERPRINT#$FINGERPRINT#" oci-credentials.hcl
                        sed -i -e "s#API_KEY#$API_KEY#" oci-credentials.hcl
                        sed -i -e "s#REGION#$ORACLE_REGION#" oci-credentials.hcl
                        '''
```

I tried to use the OracleCloudInfrastructureCredentials, however found the following error

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: fa1e826e-3211-459a-9e8a-28e57e8fbd17
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'OracleCloudInfrastructureDevOps' found among steps
```